# Is it possible to display iCal information on a webpage?

Tags: events, calendar, icalendar

I'm trying to create a mobile website that can show the current event in the user's iCal calender using an iCal link.

I was wondering if there was a way to format the information and display it. Haven't been able to find one so far.